# Adding values to grid squares in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

my question is a two parter.

First, this is my code to create a football pitch with the grid squares.

```
!pip install mplsoccer
from mplsoccer import Pitch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(np.arange(0,105, 6.5625)
y = list(np.arange(0,68,6.18))

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='uefa', line_zorder=1,
              pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#efefef')
# draw
fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(6.6, 4.125))
fig.set_facecolor('#22312b')
plt.vlines(x,0,67.9,zorder = 1, linestyles="--")
plt.hlines(y, 0, 104.9, zorder = 1,linestyles="--")
```

[image: Result of my code]

What I'd like to do with this, is add a value to the squares. Similar to this.

[image]

I'm happy to manually create those values.

After adding the values, comes the second part of the question.

```
d={'X': [45, 52], 'Y': [12, 67],'end_X':[70,82], 'end_Y':[20,44]}
d=pd.DataFrame(d)

pitch.lines(d.X,d.Y,d.end_X,d.end_Y,ax = ax, comet = True)
```

[image]

I'd like to take the value of the start of 'pass' (thin end of line), and take the value of the end of the pass, and find the difference in that, which would result in this..

```
 X  Y end_X end_Y Start End  difference
45  12  70  20  0.006   0.027   0.033
52  67  82  44  0.006   0.014   0.020
```

Any help here would be great - hope I've made myself clear and if any more information is needed, I'll add.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in drawing with mplsoccer, but I used the official reference to create a heatmap. I created the coordinates (x,y) of the event occurrence and calculated the frequency using the 'bin_statistic' function. The classification is the number of xy divisions of the pitch. not sure of the intent of your second question. I'm not sure what the intent of the second question is, do you want to find the distance of the pass or the speed?

```
from mplsoccer import Pitch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(20210819)
x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=120, size=100)
y = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=80, size=100)
# z = [np.random.random() for x in range(len(y)*len(x))]
bin_statistic = pitch.bin_statistic(x, y, statistic='count', bins=(16, 12))

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='uefa', line_zorder=1,
              pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#efefef')
# draw
fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(6.6, 4.125))
pcm = pitch.heatmap(bin_statistic, ax=ax, cmap='Blues', edgecolors='#22312b', alpha=0.5)
labels = pitch.label_heatmap(bin_statistic, color='#f4edf0', fontsize=10,
                             ax=ax, ha='center', va='center',
                             str_format='{:.01f}')
fig.set_facecolor('#22312b')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. What i'm trying to do is plot the xT (Expected Threat). Which are the numbers in the second image. The 0.001, 0.002 etc. 

What I'd like to do is automate a way where 

```if pass starts in bin [1,3] and ends in bin [4,5] - then sum those two bins. ```

Comment: Simple column summing can be done this way. `df['difference']=df['Start']+df['End']` It can also be done by creating a column with the coordinates of the event occurrences converted to Bins, grouping them and summing them. Is this the answer you are expecting?